# Using three-valued logic for set theory with singletons and equality

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Skolem wrote an interesting paper in 1960 about the use of a three-valued logic to create a set theory with true comprehension that solves Russell's paradox. That paper is [A set theory based on a certain 3-valued logic](https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10600).

He basically uses what most today would call the strong Kleene three-valued logic. The tables are:

\begin{gather*}
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
a \wedge b& 0 & ½ & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
½ & 0 & ½ & ½ \\
\hline
1 & 0 & ½ & 1 \\
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
a \vee b& 0 & ½ & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & ½ & 1 \\
\hline
½ & ½ & ½ & 1 \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{c|c}
a & \lnot a \\
\hline
0 & 1 \\
\hline
½ & ½ \\
\hline
1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\end{gather*}

So we have that $a \wedge b = \min(a,b)$, $a \vee b = \max(a,b)$, and $\lnot a = 1-a$. He then goes on to show how you can solve Russell's paradox with this system and retain true comprehension, as the Russell set $R$ simply has $R \in R = ½$. He also allows non-bounded quantifiers with $\forall$ as an infinite $\min$ and $\exists$ as an infinite $\max$.

There seems to be a real snag right away with these kinds of three-valued systems in defining singletons (and thus ordered pairs, etc.), and the subtlety is all about if equality is taken as primitive and how one can use it. Skolem, for instance, doesn't allow equality in comprehension, nor provides for any kind of primitive singleton operator, so we can't define $\{x\} := \{y \mid y = x\}$.

In two-valued logic, we can do this via extensionality instead: here we will use the symbol $x \approx y$ to mean $\forall z: (z \in x) \leftrightarrow (z \in y)$. There is a question here, however, regarding what "$\leftrightarrow$" means. It turns out there is *only* one function in this three-valued logic extending the usual bidirectional on Boolean values:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
a \leftrightarrow b& 0 & ½ & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & ½ & 0 \\
\hline
½ & ½ & ½ & ½ \\
\hline
1 & 0 & ½ & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$

This is, again, the unique bidirectional in the system Skolem is using. If we try to build the "weak singleton" using this, which would be $\{x\}_W = \{y \mid y \approx x\}$, we can get some strange results. For starters, if $x$ itself has any elements in it with membership value $½$, then $x \in \{x\}_W$ will evaluate to $½$ — it won't even be in its own weak singleton. If $x$'s membership function is purely Boolean and doesn't have any such elements, then for any $y$ which has element $z$ such that $z \in y$ takes value $½$, then we know that the above biconditional will evaluate to $½$ no matter what, and when quantified over all such $z$ we will either $0$ or $½$. Thus, for any $x$, it will always contain "extra" elements with membership value $½$, and it may even contain itself with membership value $½$.

If one tries adding *any* other bidirectional to the system, it will lose the property that all unary functions have fixed points and we will be able to rebuild Russell's paradox. With the Łukaszewicz bidirectional, for instance, we can rebuild it as $\{x \mid (x \in x) \leftrightarrow \lnot(x \in x)\}$.

Thus we are not guaranteed that singletons exist in this set theory — or if they do, you can't build them in comprehension — and thus it would seem to be very difficult to form other sets depending on them such as ordered pairs: $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$, and thus functions, etc.

One could, of course, try to "solve" this problem by simply permitting equality in comprehension to begin with. However, this can also causes problems, unless one is very careful: there's *another* version of Russell's paradox: $\{x \mid x \neq x \cup \{x\}\}$. This could perhaps be solved by not allowing union in comprehension, or perhaps prohibiting "nested comprehensions" in some form — not sure how that would work.

Summarizing all of this: it would seem like not being able to form a singleton would make for a very strange set theory, one which I cannot figure out how you could possibly do math in. On the other hand, Skolem doesn't seem to think it's a problem, and I know there are many other people who have studied non-classical logics in set theory. **Is there some way that these things can actually be useful, even though you can't build what we would normally think of as singletons?** Or, is there some standard way to somehow let you build singletons, and thus more complex sets from them, without making everything inconsistent?

Comment: Could you ask a more specific question? Of course in this weird three-valued situation, we will necessarily be giving up many things that hold in classical logic set theory. Obviously we can't "make this all work" if this is taken broadly. But what specifically are you hoping to retain?

Comment: Purely presentationally, a statement such as “$z \in y = ½$” is hard to parse (and the following “$(z \in x) \leftrightarrow (z \in y) = (z \in x) \leftrightarrow ½ = ½$” is unreasonably confusing). I suggest you use something like “$[[P]]$” to denote the truth value of $P$ and rewrite the statement as “$[[z \in y]] = ½$”.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins "But what specifically are you hoping to retain?" - singletons? Pairs? Functions? It seems basically impossible to do anything useful in set theory if you can't even build a singleton.

Comment: I am asking, what specifically does it mean to "do singletons"? My answer shows in general how one may have 3-valued truth in set theory. And those models have singletons---the assertion that every object has a singleton has positive truth value. But the assertion that a particular object is the singleton may have truth value only 1/2. This kind of thing is the nature of 3-valued set theory.

Comment: To both Joel and Gro-Tsen I've rewritten the notation in that passage and tried to clarify my question somewhat.

Comment: @LSpice, Oops, yes, that was a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to adopt three-valued truth in set theory is with paraconsistent set theory, which typically uses Kleene three-valued logic, but with the understanding that truth value 1/2 is regarded as "both true and false," and so in particular, both 1/2 and 1 are designated as instances of truth (and this logic is then called the logic of paradox). The method generalizes to paraconsistent model theory, not just set theory.

My favored way to think about it is that we are to take any two models $M_0$, $M_1$ in the same language, with the same domain. We define their paraconsistent mixture $M$ as follows: $[\![\varphi(\vec a)]\!]$ for any atomic formula $\varphi$ and individuals $\vec a$ in the domain has value $1$, if both $M_i\models\varphi(\vec a)$, and $0$ if both $M_i\models\neg\varphi(\vec a)$, and otherwise $[\![\varphi(\vec a)]\!]=1/2$. Thus, we mix together the atomic truths of the two models. One can just as easily use any collection of models.

Then, we extend the truth values by the truth-functional definition of Kleene logic. The result is a truth-functional account of 3-valued truth in the mixture model $M$.

Some accounts of paraconsistent set theory or paraconsistent model theory focus on the two-model case, but present the situation of every atomic relation being specified by its positive instances and its negative instances, setting up a duality between truth ad falsity. In a relational language, this amounts the same to the mixture as I specified it, with two models, but I regard the mixture idea as a more general approach to paraconsistent model theory, since it works with more than two models and with other logics.

A non-truth-functional approach simply defines that $[\![\varphi(\vec a)]\!]$ has value $1$, if $\varphi(\vec a)$ is true in all the models, value $0$ if it is false in all the models, and value 1/2 otherwise. This violates truth functionality, since if $\varphi$ is true in some and false in others, then $[\![\varphi\vee\neg\varphi]\!]$ has value 1 in this semantics, but value 1/2 in the truth-functional semantics.

There is an interesting connection with forcing, in the sense that for any algebra $\newcommand\A{\mathbb{A}}\A$ of truth values, including the 3-valued truth case, one can form the class $V^{\A}$ of all $\A$-names, as in forcing, and then define $\A$-valued truth $[\![\varphi(\vec\tau)]\!]$, just as in the Boolean-valued approach to forcing, except that $\A$ may not be a Boolean algebra. Things work out quite well in general. I had worked out a theory of this, but just as I was getting ready to complete my paper, I noticed the following great paper of Löwe and Tarafder, which did it even better:

- *Löwe, Benedikt; Tarafder, Sourav*, [**Generalized algebra-valued models of set theory**](https://doi.org/10.1017/S175502031400046X), Rev. Symb. Log. 8, No. 1, 192-205 (2015). [ZBL1375.03066](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1375.03066).
  This paper is really great.

Comment: Thanks @JoelDavidHamkins. So if I get your idea correctly, this approach can be related to Skolem's approach in the sense that, given some model of Skolem's theory, we can build two different models which take every proposition evaluating to $1/2$ and set it to $0$ in one model and $1$ in the other (in some manner). Thus, for any set $a$ which does exist in both models, the singleton of that set does also exist. However, your notion of equality in the paraconsistent model is itself basically multi-valued, so that $a = b$ can return $1/2$ if $b$ is only equal to $a$ in one of the models. (1/2)

Comment: The proposal I am suggesting starts with a family of classical models, and constructs from them a model with 3-valued truth, by mixing them. I don't see singletons especially as a problem or a feature, since almost every set-theoretic phenomenon displays a weird 2-valued aspect in this case. It comes with the territory.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I am not quite sure if the "equality" in this two-model approach is the same as the other "weak equality" above. Suppose you have two sets $x$ and $y$ which have nothing in them, except one element $z$ (the same element) with membership value $1/2$. This would mean that in one of your starting models, $z = \{x\}$ and in the other model $z = \{\}$, and similarly with y. When we ask $x = y$, if $z \in x$ and $z \in y$ are decided the same way in each starting model, would this be true, and false otherwise? Or would it just be $1/2$ no matter what?

Comment: Equality is always 0 or 1, since the two models have the same domain. The question is whether extensionality holds. In the non-truth-functional semantics, it holds, since it holds in each model. But in the truth-functional semantics, it has value 1/2, if one takes the value of 1/2 iff 1/2 as 1/2, which accords with the standard Kleene semantics (not Lukasiewicz).

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying. Above you said "the assertion that a particular object is the singleton may have truth value only 1/2. This kind of thing is the nature of 3-valued set theory." I interpreted this assertion as $y = \{x\}$, for some y we want to assert is the singleton with $x$ in it, or something like that. But if you are saying equality is always 0 or 1, then this can't be right. How does one assert that some object is the singleton in such a way that the answer can be 1/2?

Comment: Kleene’s logic has only 1 as a designate value. If you make also 1/2 designated, it is no longer called Kleene’s logic, but the Logic of Paradox.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, I should I have said so. I have now edited.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I accepted this answer and appreciate the response, although I still don't quite get, for instance, how singletons work. Or, in general, how set builder notation works. Normally, we can build the singleton as $\{x\} := \{y | y = x\}$. Skolem's system, on the other hand, doesn't permit equality in comprehension (and I still am not sure how singletons can be built there). It seems that your two-model system would have the singleton $\{x\}$ exist in each base model, but each model may have that a different element of the domain actually is the singleton. (1/2)

Comment: Thanks for accepting! Let me try to say a little more. You seem to insist that singletons be formed by an application of comprehension. But why? A model of set theory is simply a collection of individuals and a binary relation $\in$, and we can provide 3-valued truth using the superposition method I describe in my answer. This method provides a basically straightforward account of singletons. With such a superposition model, we can look at the truth values that every set has a singleton, or that it fulfills other instances of comprehension, and we'll get what the logic calculation gives us.

Comment: What does this look like in the mixture model? Does the notation $\{y | y=x\}$ refer unambiguously to a set at all, and if so, what are the elements of it? (I am interpreting this that you are indeed allowing equality in comprehension, which is different from Skolem.) (2/2)

Comment: For a given $x$, there are up to two different sets that each have value 1/2 of being {x}. One doesn't need to speak of comprehension at all for this calculation, since it is about truth in a model, not arguing in a theory from axioms.

Comment: Thanks @JoelDavidHamkins, sorry for missing this response. I am just a bit lost on notation. When you say each of the two possible sets "has value 1/2 of being $\{x\}$", how do we formalize this? Let's say that in model 1, some object "A" is the singleton of x, and in model 2, some object "B" is the singleton of x. If symbols for A and B exist in the language, how do we formalize the proposition that "A is the singleton of x" such that the result can be 1/2? I would like to say something like "$A = \{x\}$", but I don't get what "$\{x\}$" means in the mixture model - it need not be one set...

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to combine one's non-classical logic with a suitable conditional which is neither too weak (like the Kleene conditional) nor too strong (like the Łukasiewicz conditional). Normally, a non-truth functional conditional is used for this purpose, so you have to go beyond three- or four-valued logics to some kind of relevant logic with a worlds semantics.

As well as risking reintroducing Russell's paradox, a conditional which is too strong may also reintroduce Curry's paradox, which you get from the following instance of the naive comprehension schema:

(1) $(\forall x)( x \in y \leftrightarrow (x \in x \rightarrow p))$

From which it follows:

(2) $y \in y \leftrightarrow (y \in y \rightarrow p)$

Which can be weakened to:

(3) $y \in y \rightarrow (y \in y \rightarrow p)$

Which classically using the principle known as "contraction" simplifies to

(4) $y \in y \rightarrow p$

Which is the right hand side of (2) and so by modus ponens you get:

(5) $y \in y$

Then from (4) and (5) by modus ponens you get:

(6) $p$

Since $p$ is an arbitrary formula you could use this pattern to prove anything at all, thus trivializing the theory.

You *could* get out of this by denying modus ponens, but that would make it very hard to derive much from naïve comprehension, and so people typically adopt a conditional which does not satisfy contraction instead.

As far as I know, it's an open question which people are actively working on how much of classical mathematics one can recapture using this approach. But it shouldn't be a problem to get singletons at least.

The classic paper on this is "[Curry's Paradox](https://philpapers.org/rec/MEYCP)" in *Analysis* 1979 by Meyer, Routley and Dunn ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1093/analys/39.3.124)). You should be able to find the more recent literature by working forward from there.

Comment: Visser's [BPL](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01874706) does not derive modus ponens, for example. It is quite interesting system, with rich semantics

Comment: The problem I see, if we're trying to do this "naive comprehension with three-valued logic" thing that Skolem is doing, is that we run into problems with Lawvere's Fixed Point Theorem if we add *any* biconditional that is stronger than the one in the Kleene Logic: doing so makes it possible to create unary functions which have no fixed point, which let us build something similar to Russell's paradox again. At least if one is doing a truth-functional model for things.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia that's right the conditional has to be stronger than the Kleene conditional but not too strong to reinstate the paradoxes, the conditional has to be non-truth functional. Hence, as a far as I am aware most people engaged in this project use some kind of weak relevant logic with a possible-worlds semantics for the conditional.